# Python error: could not convert string to float - Only number from a string

Tags: python, string, floating-point, numbers

I have some Python code that pulls strings out of the crwaling output.
My code so far:

```
 import requests, json, bs4, csv, re
 import urllib

 response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://currency-api.appspot.com/api/USD/EUR.json')
 jsondata = json.loads(response.read().decode("utf-8"))
 Wechselkurs = (jsondata['rate'])


 jsonUrl = "https://www.jsox.de/s/results.json?&q=London& customerSearch=1&page=0
 response = session.get(jsonUrl, headers=headers)
 js_dict = (json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8')))

 for item in js_dict:
 prices = js_dict['searchResults']["tours"]

     for price in zip(prices):
         price_final = price.get("price")["original"]
         if price_final:
            price_end = int(float(price_final)*100*Wechselkurs)
            print(price_end)
```

This gives an error:

```
price_end = int(float(price_final)*100*Wechselkurs)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '27,44\xa0€'
```

Why can't '27,44\xa0€'be converted to a float? I guess because of the fact that I have

```
 \xa
  €
```

in my float which prevents parsing.

Can you guys help me out? Any feedback is appreciated

Comment: Are you looking to convert `27,44..` into `27.44`? You won't be able to convert the comma into a float either.

Comment: The `\xa0` is a non-breaking space. Using `re`, you may remove all non-digits at the end and replace the comma with a period - `price_final = re.sub(r'\D+$', '', price_final.replace(",", "."))`

Comment: @Wiktor: How can i remove any extra commas with your method? I´m getting the folllowing error:                                                             ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.264.71'

Comment: And what is the value you need? `1.264` or `1.26471` or any other? Are there any safe criteria to follow here? Looks like the input you have is messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...
# thanks for the suggestion @RobertSeaman
price_final = price_final[::-1].replace('.', ',').replace(',', '.', 1)[::-1].translate(None, "\xa0€,")
price_end = int(float(price_final) * 100 * Wechselkurs)
...
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate

Comment: Thanks, It is almost working. Getting the correct results but at one point I´m getting the following error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.264.71'

Comment: You can turn the string around, replace the first `,` to a `.`, and then turn it back around. Then you can remove any extra commas: `price_final = price_final[::-1].replace(',', '.', 1)[::-1].translate(None, "\xa0€,")`

Comment: @RobertSeaman and m0dem Thanks for your feedback:) Stuck into another problem:                                                                                                           price_final = price_final[::-1].replace(',', '.', 1)[::-1].translate(None, "\xa0€,")
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)                                  Any suggestions here?

Comment: @SeriousRuffy What version of python are you using? You could try `.translate(None, delete="\xa0€,")`

Comment: @RobertSeaman I´m using Python 3. I have tried it but getting a new error message:                                                                                                                              price_final = price_final[::-1].replace(',', '.', 1)[::-1].translate(None, delete="\xa0€,")
TypeError: translate() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Which version of python 3?

Comment: Try: `.translate(str.maketrans('', '', "\xa0€,"))`

Comment: @RobertSeaman Thanks for your support but I´m getting a new error for the next row:                                                                                                  price_end = int(float(price_final) * 100)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.097.68'                                    Any suggestions here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142384/discussion-between-robert-seaman-and-serious-ruffy).

Comment: As discussed, it turns out the source value was `1.097,68`, therefore, the suggested workaround was to replace all `.` with `,`. This brings the command to: `price_final = price_final[::-1].replace('.', ',').replace(',', '.', 1)[::-1].translate(None, "\xa0€,")`